# React testing bulk data within promises

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I am fairly new to react and even newer in testing.

I have a validating function for a json array of data.
The input contains data along with a parameter for each one the indicating whether the validation should fail.

```
describe('ValidatorFactory', () => {
  it('should check data', () => {

   let data = [{} ... ...];// data filled in from file.
    for (let el of country.TestData) {
      // Validate is defined elsewhere.
      validate({value: el.value}).then(
    () => {
      expect(el.valid).to.be.true;
    },
    () => {
      expect(el.valid).to.be.false;
    });
  }
}
```

I can not get expect to recognize this as a FAILING test when I run mocha.
It always shows success. No matter  if I intentionally fail it.
Is this valid testing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always return promise chains when you're done with them, which will allow any calling code (in this case, Mocha) to handle the chain further.

It looks like this is a reasonable abstraction of your code:

```
// Example validator that will reject when `obj.value` equals 2:
function validate(obj) {
  if (obj.value === 2) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("I hate 2's"));
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}

describe('ValidatorFactory', () => {

  it('should check data', () => {

    let data = [
      { value : 1, valid : true },
      { value : 2, valid : false },
      { value : 3, valid : true }
    ];

    return Promise.all(
      data.map((el) => {
        return validate(el).then(() => {
          expect(el.valid).to.be.true;
        }, () => {
          expect(el.valid).to.be.false;
        });
      })
    );
  })
})
```

The `[Promise.all( data.map(...) )` code is a shortcut for this:

```
let array = []
array.push( validate(data[0]).then(..., ...) );
array.push( validate(data[1]).then(..., ...) );
...
return Promise.all(array);
```

In other words, it generates an array of promises, and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will resolve them all.

Do note that `Promise.all()` has ["fail-fast" behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Promise.all_fail-fast_behaviour): if one of the promises it has to resolve is rejected, the promise returned by `Promise.all()` will be rejected as well, immediately. In this situation, this will happen when one of the expectations fails, which I think is acceptable.

**EDIT**: as an alternative, you can use [`chai-as-promised`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised), which adds promise support to Chai:

```
const chai   = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));

...

return Promise.all(
  data.map((el) => {
    return expect(validate(el)).to.be[ el.valid ? 'fulfilled' : 'rejected' ];
  })
);
```

Comment: Please change fullfilled to fulfilled(it gives an error). Awesome answer otherwise :-) I can't do it because I need to edit at least 6 chars in your post...which is unnecessary :D

Comment: @PotneySwitters oops =D fixed it!